# Retrigger jQuery Plugin on Window Resize?

Tags: jquery

I'm using the PerfectScrollbar jQuery plugin to handle some overflow content.  PerfectScrollbar doesn't play well with touch devices and with the way the site lays out at smaller viewport widths, it doesn't matter because I'm disabling the plugin anyway.

Long story short, I need to reinitialize the plugin in the event that a user has resized their browser window.

This is how I'm firing the plugin intially...

```
var minWidth = 800

if ( $(window).width() >= minWidth){
  $('#tasting-menu').perfectScrollbar({
  includePadding: true,
  wheelPropagation: true
});
```

I'm trying something along the lines of this to reinitialize but it's not right...

```
$(window.resize(function () {
if ( $(window).width() >= minWidth){
  $('#tasting-menu').perfectScrollbar({
    includePadding: true,
    wheelPropagation: true
    });
  }
});
```

I'm obviously a newbie at jQuery.  Is this the proper way to do this and I just have my syntax screwed up or am I just going the wrong direction entirely?

Comment: Are you getting an error in the console, or nothing at all?

Comment: You will get "tons" of function calls on $(window).resize with this approach. Consider using something like lodash's function _.debouce  example here https://lodash.com/docs#debounce

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a syntax error is causing your code to not fire. Change your code to:

```
$(window).resize(function () {
if ( $(window).width() >= minWidth){
    $('#tasting-menu').perfectScrollbar({
        includePadding: true,
        wheelPropagation: true
    });
    }
});
```

Comment: See [jQuery API documentation](http://api.jquery.com/resize/). You had `$(window.resize(...)` when it should be `$(window).resize(...)`.

Comment: In your opinion, is this the proper way to do this?

Comment: I'm not familiar with PerfectScrollbar myself. That being said, Marius Darila's suggestion of using a debounce filter is spot on. You want to make sure that there's a small delay so that you're not firing hundreds of events while the user is dragging the window or otherwise resizing it. The lodash documentation he linked to above actually uses a window.resize event as the example.

Answer (score 1):

This is how i would do it, I saw that you can pass "update" when you call perfectScrollbar so you dont need to call the initializer again http://noraesae.github.io/perfect-scrollbar/. Have fun and dont forget to add lo-dash to your script list if you want to test this :)

```
var initLayout, lazyLayout, minWidth;

minWidth = 800;

initLayout = function(options) {
  var currentWidth;
  if (options == null) {
    options = {
      includePadding: true,
      wheelPropagation: true
    };
  }
  currentWidth = $(window).width();
  if (currentWidth >= minWidth) {
    return $('#tasting-menu').perfectScrollbar(options);
  }
};

lazyLayout = _.debounce(function() {
  return initLayout('update');
}, 150);

$(window).on("resize", lazyLayout);

$(function() {
  return initLayout();
});
```

Comment: Better than mine. This should be at the top.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
$(window).on('resize', myFunctionName);

funtion myFunctionName(){
   if ( $(window).width() >= minWidth){
         $('#tasting-menu').perfectScrollbar({
         includePadding: true,
         wheelPropagation: true
       });
     }
}
```

Comment: FYI: As of jQuery 1.7+, `.on()` is preferred over `.bind()`.

Comment: Simply fixing the syntax per Nate's suggestion above works.  Is there an advantage to going about it this way?  I saw Marius' comment on my original question about "tons of function calls".  Not trying to bogart your time... I'm just trying to learn this the right way rather than simply copy and pasting solutions.

Comment: @sforcash The difference between passing an anonymous function inline (your example) and passing a function by name (this example) is just a matter of taste or personal style. Depending on how you like to organize your code, you could choose one or the other, but to the interpreter it's the same thing.